# Date Table Reorganize

Tags: database, pandas, dataframe

I need to do a transformation of a table and I don't know where to start. This is the table:

```
| Customer   Code | Activity | Start Date |
|:---------------:|:--------:|:----------:|
|       100       |     A    | 01/05/2017 |
|       100       |     A    | 19/07/2017 |
|       100       |     B    | 18/09/2017 |
|       100       |     C    | 07/12/2017 |
|       101       |     A    | 11/02/2018 |
|       101       |     B    | 02/04/2018 |
|       101       |     B    | 14/06/2018 |
|       100       |     A    | 13/07/2018 |
|       100       |     B    | 14/08/2018 |
```

Customers can perform activities A, B and C, always in that order. To carry out activity B he/she has to carry out activity A. To carry out C, he/she has to carry out activity A, then to B. An activity or cycle can be performed more than once by the same customer.

I need to reorganize the table in this way, placing the beginning and end of each step:

```
| Customer   Code | Activity | Start Date |  End Date  |
|:---------------:|:--------:|:----------:|:----------:|
|       100       |     A    | 01/05/2017 | 18/09/2017 |
|       100       |     B    | 18/09/2017 | 07/12/2017 |
|       100       |     C    | 07/12/2017 | 13/07/2018 |
|       101       |     A    | 11/02/2018 | 02/04/2018 |
|       101       |     B    | 02/04/2018 |            |
|       100       |     A    | 13/07/2018 | 14/08/2018 |
|       100       |     B    | 14/08/2018 |            |
```

Thank you! :-)

Comment: Would you like explain where is 2nd B for 101 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can use:

```
df['Start Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start Date'])
grp = (df['Customer Code'] != df['Customer Code'].shift()).cumsum().rename('grp')
df_out = df.groupby([grp,'Customer Code', 'Activity'])['Start Date'].min().reset_index()
df_out['End Date'] = df_out.groupby('Customer Code')['Start Date'].shift(-1)
df_out
```

Output:

```
   grp  Customer Code    Activity Start Date   End Date
0    1            100       A     2017-01-05 2017-09-18
1    1            100       B     2017-09-18 2017-07-12
2    1            100       C     2017-07-12 2018-07-13
3    2            101       A     2018-11-02 2018-02-04
4    2            101       B     2018-02-04        NaT
5    3            100       A     2018-07-13 2018-08-14
6    3            100       B     2018-08-14        NaT
```

#### Details:

First create a grping based on change in Customer code to group the same customer codes together, find the minimum Start Date per activity in grp.  Next, groupby 'Customer Code' and shift the start_date for the next activity up to get 'End Date'.

---

Similiar way using `drop_duplicates`:

```
df['grp'] = (df['Customer Code'] != df['Customer Code'].shift()).cumsum()
df = df.drop_duplicates(['grp','Customer Code', 'Activity']).copy()
df['End Date'] = df.groupby('Customer Code')['Start Date'].shift(-1)
df
```

Output:

```
   Customer Code    Activity Start Date  grp   End Date
0            100       A     2017-01-05    1 2017-09-18
2            100       B     2017-09-18    1 2017-07-12
3            100       C     2017-07-12    1 2018-07-13
4            101       A     2018-11-02    2 2018-02-04
5            101       B     2018-02-04    2        NaT
7            100       A     2018-07-13    3 2018-08-14
8            100       B     2018-08-14    3        NaT
```